# How to assign consecutive values to nodes in Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning my grips with programming Javascript.

I have some inputs with the same name and want to assign a consecutive number in the form of a data attribute for each one.

```
<label><input type="radio" data-number="" name="criteria1">Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" data-number=""  name="criteria1">Option 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" data-number=""  name="criteria1">Option 3</label>
```

Since there's three here, the first would be "1", the second would be "2", etc...

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get the list of items then loop through the list and assign the value to each

```
var items = document.getElementsByName('criteria1');

for(var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
  items[x].setAttribute('data-number', x + 1);
}
```

Comment: Nice to have a non jQuery answer

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with jQuery via the `each` method:

```
$('input').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('data-number', index + 1);
});
```